# Q# install issue

Tags: programming, q#

I have followed the instructions to install Q# using conda as recommended, and given by MS. When I try to import `qsharp` from my virtual env within a Python program, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp.Workspace[0] QS5022: No identifier with the name “v” exists.
```

Does any one have experience of this issue please?  I have googled it but to no avail.

I use .NET run perfectly with `example.qs` and `example.csproj` files, but I would like to work within VSCode.
(Ubuntu v. 20.04, .NET SDK v. 3.1, Python v. 3.7 + latest Miniconda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `import qsharp`, it will try to compile the `.qs` files in the current folder so the corresponding operations are available from Python. It seems the Q# compiler is having some problems with one of the files.
Try to see if any of the `.qs` files in the directory have any syntax errors, and try removing the `obj` folder with temporary files if it exists.

Comment: Thank you El, I got there in the end after fixing some errors, as you pointed out